View a 3d object with texture and save it to a .gif
I can visualize my 3d object with texture with the following script but the whole image is too dark. How can I make the whole thing lighter?
Plus, if you know how to save it as a rotating gif that would be great, I didn't find the solution.
    import numpy as np
    import trimesh
    from PIL import Image

    im = Image.open("4653_part_1.1001.jpg")
    mesh = trimesh.load('4653_part_1.obj',process=False)
    tex = trimesh.visual.TextureVisuals(image=im)
    mesh.visual.texture = tex
    mesh.show()

Best regards
Chloé
